# How to implement RBAC permission in REST API (Nest.js Best Practice)

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, nestjs, rbac

I am writing a REST API service where I need to add a layer of authorization for the endpoints I provide. I implemented authorization by using discrete permission on every controller using a guard/middleware.

```
  @Get('/clients')
  @hasPermissions('read', 'all')
  @UseGuards(PermissionsGuard)
  async getClient(@Query() query, @Res() res) { 
      ...
  }
```

My question is I need to add a layer of access depending on the owner of the resource. For example, if the user has an admin previllages he/she can see clients created by `everyone`, however, if the user has a privilege that is lower than the admin he/she can `only` see a client which created by himself/herself.

Comment: I just put the answer here, that should resolve that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58220626/role-based-access-control-with-dynamic-roles/73872294#73872294